# Gevent-socketio on heroku

Tags: heroku, socket.io, gevent

I trying to use gevent-socketio on heroku, i've build the application and it works localy with gunicorn. But once I push it to heroku it gives me server internal error. I've traced the error with heroku logs --tail and it gives me this error. https://gist.github.com/3673165

I did some research and noticed that for sockeio heroku demands some additional [setup.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)
How do I do this with gevent-socketio? Is it even posible to setup this?

I've read that heroku doesnt support websockets but supports socketio, so I wonder if is it posible cause gevent-socketio uses gevent-websocket...or am I wrong?

So please if anyone managed to setup this, tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about why the internal error, but as to your question re the "setup": these are 2 keyword arguments you need to pass to an instance of SocketIOServer.

As a quick hack, you can copy sgunicorn.py to your project dir, and modify it to pass the required values, something like:

```
    server = self.server_class(
        self.socket, application=self.wsgi,
        spawn=pool, handler_class=self.wsgi_handler,
        resource=self.resource, policy_server=self.policy_server,
        ## add your stuff here
        transports=['xhr-polling'], ## heroku will only support xhr-polling transport
        heartbeat_interval=10, ## client will send a heartbeat every 10 seconds
        heartbeat_timeout=15, ## server will expect said heartbeat every 15 seconds (give it time to arrive...)
        close_timeout=60, ## if client did not re-connect in 60 seconds, it will give up
    )
```

However, I am sorry to say I don't think this has anything to do with your sleep(1.0) exiting.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Nitzan, the key is to limit the transports to 'xhr-polling' and to set the time intervals for the client polling duration and timeout.  If you're using gunicorn, Nitzan's instructions should work.

**You also need to do this for the client-side.**  In particular, make sure the polling duration you're giving on the server-side matches the polling duration on the client-side.